# How do I use ASP.NET Session object in my MVC 3 web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-state

I need to use session in my MVC 3 web app like I used to do in my old ASP.NET web app. I need to save some values, and then access it from any of my controllers and all other views.

Please give me a very simple example following the best practices.

I am new in MVC development and started with MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use session the same way you do in webforms.

In your controllers you can simply use the `Session` object. You could save the state of a model in `Session` and pass the result to your view.

Answer (score 3):

Basic `session` usage remains same for both mvc and webforms.
In addition to that you have `ViewData`, `ViewBag` also to store between controller and view

Refer to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2009/09/22/strongly-typed-session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) article for creating a helper class for using strongly typed sessions in mvc.